# Use of OpenNTF Domino API outside in non-Domino container

Tags: lotus-domino

Is it possible to use OpenNTF Domino API outside of domino application container?

http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API

Can it be used in tomcat or websphere or jboss or just in standalone application to access domino data using DIIOP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the OpenNTF Domino API is not compatible with IBM's DIIOP implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API in a standalone application as long as you sit on the same machine and can use the Notes C core directly. With sufficient access for the user a client installation could do.

If direct access to a Domino server (or a Notes client) is an option, check out [how it works](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9MQNB4)

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you stwissel for your response. We don't have direct access to domino server. I think our only option is to write some wrapper/framework to ease pain of IBM's native apis.

Comment: Install a Notes client. Then you can use the OpenNTF API. Or have them switch on Domino Data services. Or write an XPages app as proxy and use REST. I would try to avoid DIIOP as much as you can

Comment: Your recommendation to not to use DIIP is because of performance reasons or is it quirky? Using REST seems to be good idea but it also involves http connections. Do you think performance would be significantly better in case of REST?

Comment: Thanks @stwissel . I also found another open source project that is based on Spring framework and seems to have some nice features such as connection pooling, session management etc. 
[link] https://www.assembla.com/code/efor-integracion-ws/subversion/nodes/491/codigo/trunk/integracion/core

Comment: DIIOP hasn't got much attention for a decade. So the body of knowledge is slim.  So you would be on your own for trouble shooting. I would always try to abstract the task: have a light http api and do the heavy lifting in an OSGi plug-in

Comment: The spring project seems dormant for 4 years. And you still have Diiop to deal with